# AWS Artifact & AWS Organizations

Tags: amazon-web-services, standards-compliance

I want to download a SOC 2 TYPE 2 report from AWS artifact. In my company we use AWS Organizations to manage 20 different AWS accounts. I was wondering if it would be possible to download **a single** SOC 2 TYPE 2 report from the organisation management account that includes the report for each account, **instead of downloading one for each AWS account.**

There is no information regarding this in the docs. Has anyone of you done something similar?

Comment: You might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws